# Recieving warning about casting "from pointer to integer of different size" while compiling c in gcc

Tags: c

I am trying to learn C, and I'm trying to cast a `char` into an `int` to extract the ASCII value.  However, when I try to compile this in GCC, I get this warning:

```
warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
     ascii = (int) letter;
```

I'm trying to do a simple program that asks for a single character, scans for it, then casts it as an int to get the ASCII value, printing that value.  I've initialized the `letter` variable as `char*` and `ascii` as `int`.  I've tried using the placeholders`%s`, `%c`, and `%1s` for the `letter` variable, but it isn't work.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char* letter;
int ascii;

int main(){
    printf("Please input a charcter:");
    scanf("%s", letter);
    ascii = (int) letter;
    printf("\n The ASCII value of %s is %d.\n", letter, ascii);
}
```

What I'd expect to happen is that `"Please input a character:"` would print, then a character, such as `a`, would be typed, and then it would print, for example, `"The ASCII value of a is 97."

Instead, when I type something, it prints `"The ASCII value of (null) is zero."`  During compilation, it prints out the error listed above.  This is not what's supposed to happen.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: `%s` is not the format specifier for a character.  You have a pointer to nowhere.  All the rest of your problems are a result of these two facts.

Comment: I suggest learning from reference material instead of trying things and seeing if they work or not

Comment: If you only want to convert individual characters, it may be safer and easier to take a character as an input (which can then directly be converted to an ascii value)

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%s", letter);` and `char* letter;`  1) the pointer `letter` is never set to point to any memory owned by the application so writing to where it points is undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.  2) the input format specifier '%s' has no limit on how many characters can be input AND always appends a NUL byte to the input AND leaves the newline in `stdin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't casting a char to an int, you are casting a pointer to a char to an int.

```
int main(){
    // define as an actual char, not a char*
    char letter;
    int ascii;

    printf("Please input a character:");
    // scan a character, not a string.  Pass in the address of the char
    scanf("%c", &letter);
    ascii = (int)letter;
    printf("\n The ASCII value of %c is %d.\n", letter, ascii);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

//char* letter; //moving to stack from data segment
int ascii;

int main(){
    char letter[10] = {0};//allocing 10 bytes here, all initialized null chars
    printf("Please input a charcter:");
    scanf("%c", &letter); //not checking return value here, bad form
    ascii = (int) letter[0]; //casting only the first char
    printf("\n The ASCII value of %s is %d.\n", &letter, ascii);
}
```

Results in the output that you wanted:

```
Please input a charcter:
 The ASCII value of a is 97.
```

This is bad code, and ive commented on some lines to help add some clarity.

```
#include <stdio.h>

//char* letter; //moving to stack from data segment
int ascii;

int main(){
    char letter[10] = {0};//allocing 10 bytes here, all initialized null chars
    printf("Please input a charcter:");
    scanf("%s", &letter); //not checking return value here, bad form
    ascii = (int) letter[0]; //casting only the first char
    printf("\n The ASCII value of %s is %d.\n", &letter, ascii);
    printf("\n The ASCII value of %s is %d.\n", &letter[1], (int)letter[1]);
}
```

With input ab, changing %c to %s gets both charaters (which seems like what you wanted in the first place?)

```
Please input a charcter:
 The ASCII value of ab is 97.


 The ASCII value of b is 98
```

.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `%hhd` format specifier

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char letter;
    fputs(stdout, "Please input a charcter:");
    letter = getchar();
    
    printf("\nThe ASCII value of %c is %hhd.\n", letter, letter);
    return 0;
}
```